# Can't write to console in async C# code when called from powershell ISE

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, asynchronous

I have a PowerShell script that needs to call C# to do work, some of it asynchronously.  While debugging some errors that only occur when the C# code is called from PowerShell, I noticed something I wasn't expecting.  In the C# code, if I made a call to `Console.WriteLine` it wrote to the PowerShell console as expected **unless** I was using PowerShell ISE and it was called after I did an await in an async function.

Here's a sample script that shows the issue:

```
$source = @"
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class TestClass
{   
    public static int TestWrapper()
    {
        var task = TestAsync();
        task.Wait();
        return task.Result;
    }

    private static async Task<int> TestAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Before await");
        await Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(2000); return; });
        Console.WriteLine("After await");
        return 2;
    }
}

"@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $source
[TestClass]::TestWrapper()
```

In here, I'm just calling an asynchronous function, waiting for it to complete, and returning the result.  Inside the function, I just try to log before and after putting a thread to sleep for a few seconds before returning a value so that I know that the function fully executed.

I would expect to see:

```
Before await
After await
2
```

And that's what I see when running as a C# console application or in basic PowerShell, but when running through PowerShell ISE, I see:

```
Before await
2
```

Can anyone explain why that would be?

Comment: It works fine when I try it.

Comment: You know, I didn't think there'd be a difference between powershell and PowerShell ISE, but I guess there is.

Comment: Ah, yes.  I can reproduce your problem when running PowerShell ISE.

Comment: This is a guess, but is there a working SynchronizationContext in a console application? Could Powershell ISE mess with that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PowerShell ISE use [`Console.SetOut`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.console.setout.aspx) with [`HostTextWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.windows.powershell.gui.internal.hosttextwriter) to capture and print `Console.WriteLine` output on PowerShell ISE host window. And `HostTextWriter` redirect `Console.WriteLine` to PowerShell host only if host registered ([`HostTextWriter.RegisterHost`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.powershell.gui.internal.hosttextwriter.registerhost)) for current thread.

In absence of `SynchronizationContext` continuation caused by `await` keyword will be executed in arbitrary thread pool thread, which likely does not have any registered PowerShell host to redirect `Console.WriteLine` to.